# HHVM stops working, (111: Connection Refused) message on Nginx with PageSpeed

Tags: wordpress, nginx, pagespeed, hhvm

I've recently set up a WordPress blog on a VPS with **Ubuntu 12.04 LTS, HHVM, Nginx** (with the PageSpeed module included), and **MariaDB**. Everything runs really fast, but in the last few days I've noticed that HHVM stops working suddenly and from that moment the *error.log* shows first this message:

```
2014/09/18 12:27:56 [error] 24442#0: *121276 recv() failed (104: Connection reset by peer) while reading response header from upstream, client: 150.146.136.21, server: xxxxx.com, request: "POST /wp-login.php?PageSpeed=noscript HTTP/1.0", upstream: "fastcgi://127.0.0.1:9000", host: "xxxxx.com"
```

and then several messages with URLs corresponding to articles people are trying to read, but always with a 111 error:

```
2014/09/18 14:03:28 [error] 24442#0: *133594 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 66.249.78.121, server: xxxxx.com, request: "GET /2008/11/27/thanksgiving-whatever/ HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://127.0.0.1:9000", host: "www.xxxx.com"
```

I'd say it has something to do with the PageSpeed module, but why is HHVM affected and not Nginx? DO you have some hint?

Thank

Comment: I am having this issue without pagespeed installed on a pure nginx+hhvm setup. I've had to revert to php-fpm for now until I can find the solution.

Comment: Looks like the HHVM daemon went down. Can you show us /var/log/hhvm/error.log? (note: not that nginx error log). There might also be a stacktrace-*.log file in /tmp that I'd be interested in.

Comment: The most recent stacktrace*.log is this (http://pastebin.com/RL5bCp89) there are also perf-*.map files in case you want to take a look. The error.log from hhvm has a problem: it doesn't show dates/times, right? It's difficult to locate the problem, the file is pretty big now and lots of errors duplicated :(

Comment: I've seen that the /var/log/hhvm/error.log now shows some MariaDB related errors. Maybe this is useful: the errors are similar to this one, but with different queries (such as the whole post_content): 

SlowTimer [1371ms] at runtime/ext_mysql: slow query: SELECT * FROM wp_comments  WHERE comment_approved = '1' AND comment_post_ID = 6319  ORDER BY comment_date_gmt ASC

So I'll have a look at that, but in the meantime, any hints?